# kurento: How to pass guint8 * to java server as an int[]

Tags: kurento

I am trying to send the `GstBuffer` objects `map.data` to the java server. I have created an event with a parameter as `int[]` but when raising the event I am getting the following error at compile time.

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘kurento::module::vadcustomfilter::BufferReceived::BufferReceived(std::shared_ptr<kurento::MediaObject>, const char [16], int*)’

BufferReceived event (shared_from_this (), "Buffer Received", ((int *)buffer));
```

`map.data` is of type `guint8 *`

is there something wrong am doing in type casting ?

I tried sending `map.data` as `std::string` but at java side I am not receiving the complete string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting `guint8*` to `char*` is fine, because only the sign changes. Casting to `int *` is not OK because the size is different, in order to send this kind of events, you may need to copy the array of `guint8` to an array of `int`. But think that this is not a fast operation, nor serializing this big event, so do not expect to have a great performance.

Furthermore, what kurento events expects (you should check the signature of `BufferReceived`) when you declare an array is a `std::vector<int>`, so in any case you need to create the array and copy the content.